# Is there a way to reliably rotate SVG text within a resizable graphic?

Tags: svg, text

I'm building an SVG which displays a fairly standard X-Y plot with axis labels. I'd like the y-axis label (on the left-hand of the graph) to be shown vertically, with the whole text rotated 90 degrees. For example, to graph `velocity` / `time`, the y-axis would be "Velocity" with the V shown at the top of the graph and the "y" toward the bottom.

My SVG is build with all sizes and distances computed in `%`, so e.g. a line might be rendered this way:

```
<line x1="5%" y1="8%" x2="10%" y2="6%" />
```

This was done so that the graphic would be "resized" to fill any space given to it by the enclosing application, web page, etc.

I know how to rotate text (`transform="rotate(Θ, cx, cy)"`) but that doesn't work with percentages for the `cx` and `cy` values. I've tried wrapping the text in a `<g>` and rotating that (likewise with `<svg>`), but the coordinate system seems to be inherited from the parent, so I can't rotate around the "origin" of the `<g>` or `<svg>` and then place the final item relative to the outer coordinate system (at least I haven't figured out how).

Given that I'm using percentages for everything, is there a way to rotate text in the way I'd like?

Answer (score 2):

As a first note, transforms do not inherit, but define a new coordinate system for the element and all its children. That might look likw a semantic detail, but to understand SVG you will need to think in terms current coordinate systems and their transformation, otherwise large parts of the spec will seem confusing.

Transformations with the [`transform` attribute](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/coords.html#TransformAttribute) and [CSS transforms](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-transforms-1) are currently not really compatible. The SVG `rotate()` function does not reliably take unit identifiers cross-browser, and the CSS `rotate()` function has no parameters for the rotation center, but can use the `transform-origin` property. Consequently, there are two solutions for your problem. Both are described with the text anchor as center of rotation

#### The CSS way

`transform-origin` is a CSS property that takes a list of two lengths to describe the center of rotation. As a default, the center of the rotation is the center of the rotated object. For text content, that might pose a few uncertainties about where the *vertical* center lies. It is better to define an explicit `transform-box:view-box` and use the positioning attributes again.

```css
line {
    stroke: red;
}

text {
    font-family: sans-serif;
    font-size: 15px;
}

.cross {
    transform: rotate(90deg);
    transform-origin: 20% 20%;
    transform-box: view-box;
}
```

```html
<svg width="200" height="150">
    <line x1="20%" x2="20%" y1="0" y2="100%" />
    <line x1="0" x2="100%" y1="20%" y2="20%" />
    <text class="along" x="20%" y="20%">label</text>
    <text class="cross" x="20%" y="20%">label</text>
</svg>
```

Note that IE/Edge [do not support](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform-box#Browser_compatibility) this syntax.

#### The SVG way

SVG supports a second mechanism that result in a new coordinate system: defining a new viewport. For that, you have to nest a `<svg>` element. While currently defining a `transform` attribute on a `<svg>` element is not fully supported, you can set new `x` and `y` attributes to effectively achieve a translation.

That way, you can first position your text at the origin of its local coordinate system, rotate it in place, and only then move it to its new position with a percentage length.

```css
line {
    stroke: red;
}

text {
    font-family: sans-serif;
    font-size: 15px;
}

svg svg {
    overflow: visible;
}
```

```html
<svg width="200" height="150">
    <line x1="20%" x2="20%" y1="0" y2="100%" />
    <line x1="0" x2="100%" y1="20%" y2="20%" />
    <text class="along" x="20%" y="20%">label</text>
    <svg x="20%" y="20%">
        <!-- x, y and transform center all default to 0 -->
        <text class="cross" transform="rotate(90)">label</text>
    </svg>
</svg>
```

You need to set `overflow:visible` on the inner svg to ensure content that ends up outside the new viewport is still visible. (In the above example, this is not the case, but if you used for example a `text-anchor:middle`, the label would start at a negative y value.